# How to build an administration UI with mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

I'm using RoR3 with mongoid, and I would like to get an easy administration UI like typus or activescaffold over activerecord.

Any hint ? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to contribute required functionality to:

- [ActiveScaffold](https://github.com/vhochstein/active_scaffold) using these ideas [Using Active Scaffold On A Data Structure – No Database Table](https://github.com/activescaffold/active_scaffold/wiki/Using-Active-Scaffold-On-A-Data-Structure-%E2%80%93-No-Database-Table)
- [rails_admin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin) using these ideas [issue 105](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues/105)

Answer (score 0):

Mongoid is on the feature list of rails_admin now: 
https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin#features